# How to create a sequence with start with value that is a query

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence

I saw this same question here [Create a Sequence with START WITH from Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461267/create-a-sequence-with-start-with-from-query) but it does not work. It has 12 up votes so I'm not sure why it's not working for me.

This is what I have:

```
declare
    l_new_seq INTEGER;
begin
   select max(expense_detailid) + 1
   into   l_new_seq
   from   expense_detail;

   execute immediate 'create sequence expense_detail_seq 
                      start with ' || l_new_seq || ' increment by 1';
end;
/
```

And this is the error I get:

```
ORA-06550: line 3, column 17:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "create sequence expense_detail_seq start with " when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "create sequence expense_detail_seq start with " to continue. (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 27 in '
    BEGIN
      immediate <*>'create sequence expense_detail_seq start with ' || l_new_seq || ' increment by 1';
    END;
  ')

ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What you say you're doing is fine, but the error message you've shown indicates that you're actually running something different. The `execute` keyword is missing (which gives this error) and you have an extra begin/end wrapper. I'm wondering if your client (I'm guessing this is a Perl script from the DBD reference?) is replacing `execute` with `exec`, and is maybe running separate statements. The quoted line number is confusing though. You'd get exactly this if you did `exec immediate ...` from a SQL*Plus prompt, except it would say line 1. If it's in a script, can you show the context?

Comment: Works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4d6f7/1  Which tool do you use to run the statement? Maybe it does not recognize the `/` delimiter?

Comment: I created a .sql file and I'm using yasql to load the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make all the text in a single line.  Or at least each literal.

Also, what is the product/utility and product version ?

Comment: Begin and execute are each on their own full lines, no breaks (I added them here just for display).
As for version:
Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
CORE    10.2.0.4.0      Production
TNS for Linux: Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production

Comment: Unless it's confusing the client, it isn't usually necessary for it all to be on one line; it would be with `exec` from SQL*Plus (though you can use continuation characters even then), but not with `execute immediate`. A literal can split over a line here though.

Comment: @dazed-and-confused  It's extremely strange.  It executes with no issue in my configuration.  Can you type the text from scratch or otherwise remove control characters?  It's the only I can think of.

Comment: Ok so after trying to type line by line, I noticed a program right away with my DECLARE. Apparently, the DECLARE doesn't like being on its own line. I thought I tried putting it together but I didn't. Once I got the DECLARE var_name INTEGER on one line, it worked...
And this is why i'm dazed-and-confused.

Comment: @dazed-and-confused  The only **other** thing I can think of is creating a stored procedure and executing it.  This **should** be working!

Comment: @dazed-and-confused  I still think you had a control character.  Of course now I think near the `declare`.