# Unable to dynamically start sequence

Tags: plsql, sequence

Based on [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461267/create-a-sequence-with-start-with-from-query), I created this code:

```
DECLARE
    new_employee_id INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(EMP_ID) + 1 INTO new_employee_id FROM EMPLOYEE;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE SEQUENCE primary_key_seq START WITH ' || new_employee_id || ' INCREMENT BY 1';
END;
/
```

OBS: perhaps using a sequence to auto increment the primary key of a table doesn't make much sense, but this is a school exercise and that's what we're supposed to do, so please disregard that aspect.

This is the error I have:
ERROR AT LINE 1
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
ORA-06512: at line 5

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no CREATE OR REPLACE SEQUENCE option, so you must use the CREATE SEQUENCE Statement and the a DROP statement if you need to drop it first.

```
DECLARE
    new_employee_id INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(EMP_ID) + 1 INTO new_employee_id FROM EMPLOYEE;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE SEQUENCE primary_key_seq START WITH ' || new_employee_id || ' INCREMENT BY 1';
END;
/
```

Comment: OMG... how could I not have see that :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

there is no REPLACE in create sequence command check [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6014.htm) (wich is always a good idea ;-)

should be

```
DECLARE
    new_employee_id INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(EMP_ID) + 1 INTO new_employee_id FROM EMPLOYEE;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE SEQUENCE primary_key_seq START WITH ' || new_employee_id || ' INCREMENT BY 1';
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

This question begs another question - *why* are you trying to drop and re-add a sequence? You should never need to do this. Create the sequence once:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE PRIMARY_KEY_SEQ
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  NOCACHE;
```

Then, **use it** in your code:

```
DECLARE
  new_employee_id INTEGER;
BEGIN
  new_employee_id := PRIMARY_KEY_SEQ.NEXTVAL;

  INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE_MAYBE_EMPLOYEES
    (ID, WHATEVER, WHATEVER_ELSE)
  VALUES
    (new_employee_id, 'WHATEVER', 'WHATEVER_ELSE');
END;
```

The whole purpose of the sequence is to provide unique, non-repeating values. Going out to the table, grabbing the MAX(ID), and recreating the sequence to start from there is sort of backwards from the way a sequence should be used. Create a sequence once, then use it many times.

Hopefully this helps.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: I've been doing a lot of trial and error in order to figure out this exercise, that's why I needed to ensure a previously created sequence was dropped before I proceed. Please don't interpret my code as a real life example, it's just a school exercise.